# How to Run a Second SSH command using SSHPass Whenever Already Connected Via Python

Tags: python, ssh, sshpass

I'm trying to make a system (that will eventually be turned into a web interface) in order to ssh into a Raspberry Pi Zero and execute a python script to remotely control a GoPro. Currently, I have the part working of remotely controlling the GoPro, however, I want to split different functionality into different methods such as one to connect to the GoPro, another to take a video, another to take a single picture, etc. 
Here is the code I have to do this so far:

```
import os

def connectToGoPro(user, host, password):
    command = "sshpass -p "+password+ " ssh " + user+"@"+host+" 'cd /boot; ls -l'"
    os.system(command) //This bit works

def takePhotos(fileName, captureCount):
    os.system("python3 ''"+ fileName + "' "+str(captureCount)+"'") //This bit doesn't work
```

Whenever I run the **connectToGoPro()** method, it successfully ssh's into the Raspberry Pi Zero. The problem I'm having is that when I run the **takePhotos** method, it runs the command in my PC's command line rather than the Pi Zero's. How do I go about fixing this so that the takePhotos command runs on the device I'm SSH'd into rather than my PC?

Thanks very much.